# What can i do to remove the white mark on the corner of this Dialog?

Tags: javafx

I just try to remove this white corner.
I just tried to remove it with transparent fill and transparent stage style but i don't understand.

https://www.noelshack.com/2019-15-4-1554985811-unknown.png

https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/544126761169059870/565874307176071208/unknown.png

The css file:

```
 .dialog-pane{
    -fx-border-color:black;
    -fx-border-width:2.0px;
    -fx-border-radius: 10;
    -fx-background-radius: 10;  
 }


.dialog-pane > .button-bar > .container {
  -fx-background-color:grey;
  -fx-background-radius: 0 0 10 10;
}

.dialog-pane > .content.label {
   -fx-padding: 0.5em 0.5em 0.5em 0.5em;
   -fx-background-color: grey;
   -fx-background-radius: 10 10 0 0;
   -fx-text-fill:black;
   -fx-font-size:15.0px;
}





/**Costumization of Buttons**/
.dialog-pane .button{
   -fx-background-color:black;
   -fx-text-fill:white;
   -fx-wrap-text: true;
   -fx-effect: dropshadow( three-pass-box, black, 10.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
   -fx-cursor:hand;
 }

.dialog-pane .button:hover{     
  -fx-background-color:white;
  -fx-text-fill:black;
  -fx-font-weight:bold; 
 }
```

The java file:

```
public Dialog<ButtonType> getDialogConfirmChoice() {
    if (dialogConfirmChoice == null) {
        dialogConfirmChoice = new Dialog<ButtonType>();

        DialogPane diaPane = dialogConfirmChoice.getDialogPane();
        diaPane.getStylesheets().add("file:ressource/style/styleDialogConfirmation.css");



        diaPane.getButtonTypes().clear();
        diaPane.getButtonTypes().addAll(getOkButtonType(), getCancelButtonType());
        dialogConfirmChoice.setContentText("This is your last word?");
        dialogConfirmChoice.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);



        dialogConfirmChoice.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);

        //Set the scene of the dialog to transparent to don't have a white background. This is not the main scene.
        diaPane.getScene().setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        //grab your root here
        diaPane.setOnMousePressed(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                xOffset = event.getSceneX();
                yOffset = event.getSceneY();
            }
        });

        //move around here
        diaPane.setOnMouseDragged(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                dialogConfirmChoice.setX(event.getScreenX() - xOffset);
                dialogConfirmChoice.setY(event.getScreenY() - yOffset);
            }
        });


        //diaPane.setContent(vbox);
    }
    return dialogConfirmChoice;
}
```